# Collect Document Workflow

Tags: document, collection

I wanted to know if there are any easy ways to make a workflow which emails a bunch of users to ask them to submit their resume. If they don't, then send a reminder email and eventually an email to their manager. Is there any workflow I can work off of that collects documents?

Thanks!